# MySQL Raw and Column Combined Fetch

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First of all I don't know if my question title is right or not, but let me explain the scenario.

1. I have table "documnets_table"
   with columns: id, customer_id, doucment_type, issuedate, validity_date...etc.
2. I want to do a check in my php web service so that I can check for the validity of documents from the documents_table.
3. But here for a customer document_type and user_id associated with a customer may have two entries as I am storing two documents ( driving license and insurance details) in this table.

So the bellow is my code to check the validity of these two documents and to generate the appropriate response back to the user.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT validity_date, status from documents_table WHERE user_id = '$id'");

            $validity_array = array();    
            while($doc_row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                $validity_array[] = $doc_row['validity_date'];
            }

            $current_date = date("Y-m-d");
            $driving_license_exp_date = $validity_array[0];    
            $vehicle_insurance_exp_date = $validity_array[1];
```

My problem is that its not necessary that the table contains the documnet type as the given order always, I mean as in my code, I expect the first one will be always driving license and the second one is insurance.

How can modify the above code along with document type check ?

Comment: a) stop using `mysql` functions, they are deprecated and in PHP7 removed. use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. b) have you tried adding an `ORDER BY`? or selecting the type and checking it?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create another table for identifying the type of attached documents?

doc_type_tb:

```
 doc_type_id |   doc_type_desc
-------------+------------------
      1      |   Driving License
      2      |  Vehicle Insurance
```

Then, add another column on your `documents_table`, which will be named for example - `doc_type_id`:

```
 id | customer_id | doc_type_id |  issuedate  | validity_date | 
----+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
  1 |      1      |       1     |  2016-12-19 |   2019-12-19  |
  2 |      1      |       2     |  2016-12-19 |   2019-12-19  |
```

(*Though you have `document_type` column already for your `documents_table`, which were not explained on how you use it. I'm assuming that this column is only in a text format*)

Then, create a join query:

```
SELECT a.validity_date, a.status, b.doc_type_desc
    FROM documents_table a
    LEFT JOIN doc_type_tb b ON a.doc_type_id = b.doc_type_id
    WHERE a.user_id = '$id'
```

With this approach, you can just create a new type of document in your `doc_type_tb` for a "dynamic/more future-proof" approach of your system (*in case you want to add more document for each user*)

---

On a side note, please defer from using the deprecated [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead.